# Constrained optimization with just $+1$ and $-1$

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have to maximize the quadratic form
$$
{\cal F}={\bf s}^TQ{\bf s}
$$
where $Q$ is a finite square matrix such that $Q=Q^\dagger$ and ${\bf s}$ can contain only the values $\pm 1$ as components. The difficulty I met was to fix properly the constraints in such way to maintain the components of the solution ${\bf s}$ to be only $\pm 1$.

Having the correct formulation of the problem through Lagrange multipliers would already be of great help but whatever hint will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not really a Lagrange multiplier type problem. It's a non-linear (quadratic) integer programming problem. If you have more information about the structure of the matrix, you may be able to exploit that information, but otherwise, I doubt you can do much better than a full search. You do have one free choice: You can force the first component, say, to be $+1$, thus reducing the search space to $2^{n-1}$ candidate vectors (where the matrix is $n{\,\times\,}n$).

Comment: A state of the art tool for this kind of thing is http://lipn.univ-paris13.fr/BiqCrunch/